# Code Error Pop Up inside cell as #DIV/0! after code runs through all cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I am working on macro scripting where Finance formula is used also inside the worksheet**

**I am able to receive the result values when there are different values in Row1 but when there are transpose values of Column 1, then I receive Error.**

> Please see the code below and attached two screenshots also

```
function MyFunction(){

  var sd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SD');
  var cr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CORRELATION');

  var lr = cr.getLastRow();//find last row 
  var lc = cr.getLastColumn();//find last column 

  var data = cr.getRange(1, 1, lr, lc).getValues();
  var data1 = sd.getRange(1, 1, 999,9999).getValues();

  var c = 2
  for ( var i = 1; i <= lc - 1; i++ ){
    var r = 2

    for ( var j = 1; j <= lr - 1; j++ ){

      //Logger.log(data[0][i] + " - " +data[j][0])
      sd.getRange("B1").setValue(data[0][i])
      sd.getRange("S1").setValue(data[j][0])
      cr.getRange(r, c).setValue(sd.getRange("H8").getValue())//error comes here
      r = r + 1
    }
    c = c+ 1
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Task Completed!', 'Status');
}
```

[Picture 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4jdy.jpg)
[Picture 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsKic.jpg)

Comment: @BigBen Kindly advise how to remove the error.

Comment: Your question seems to be about debugging your script.  It would help people understand your issue better if you provided a sample sheet, with the script, and if you described what you have done to try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @kirkg13
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pNSJuSwvtOtxSi7ZbP2d5nozgTsVaoCgkrPQfAqSv6A/edit#gid=0

Kindly access the sheet here. Code is present inside the Script Editor

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you incrementing your column or row outside of the limits of your sheet.  Start with the following code and rewrite your function:

```
function MyFunction(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sd=ss.getSheetByName('SD');
  var cr=ss.getSheetByName('CORRELATION');
  var data=cr.getRange(1, 1, cr.getLastRow(), cr.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var data1=sd.getRange(1, 1, sd.getLastRow(),sd.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
    for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++) {

    }
  }
}
```